# Error in setting my character in the right color pixel in java

Tags: java, position, entity

I am having some issues trying to set my character to spawn in the right color spot in my map sheet in java.
In the vídeos that I am watching to learn this I have every single line code identical to the vídeo but yet my character instead of spawning in the right spot is spawning in the up middle corner of the screen.

I'm using those code lines to make him and all Tiles and Entities spawn in the right spot :

```
public class World {
    
    private Tile[] tiles;
    public static int WIDTH,HEIGHT;

    public World(String path) {
        try {
            BufferedImage map = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
            int[] pixels = new int[map.getWidth() * map.getHeight()];
            WIDTH = map.getWidth();
            HEIGHT = map.getHeight();
            tiles = new Tile[map.getWidth() * map.getHeight()];
            map.getRGB(0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight(), pixels, 0, map.getWidth());
            for(int xx = 0; xx < map.getWidth(); xx++) {
                for(int yy = 0; yy < map.getHeight(); yy++) {
                    int pixelAtual = pixels[xx + (yy*map.getWidth())];
                    tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new FloorTile(xx*16,yy*16, Tile.TILE_FLOOR);
                    if(pixelAtual == 0xFF000000) {
                        //FLOOR
                        tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new FloorTile(xx*16,yy*16, Tile.TILE_FLOOR);
                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFFFFFFFF){
                        //PAREDE
                        tiles[xx + (yy * WIDTH)] = new FloorTile(xx*16,yy*16, Tile.TILE_WALL);

                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFF0026FF) {
                        //Player    
                        Game.player.setX(xx*16);
                        Game.player.setY(yy*16);
                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFFFF0000){
                        //Enemy
                        
                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFFFF00DC) {
                        //WEAPON
                        
                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFFFF7F7F) {
                        //LIFEPACK
                        
                    }else if(pixelAtual == 0xFFFFD800) {
                        //BULLET
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for(int xx = 0; xx < WIDTH; xx++) {
            for(int yy = 0; yy < HEIGHT; yy++) {
                Tile tile = tiles[xx + (yy*WIDTH)];
                tile.render(g);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

But when I use these two code lines that are from my Entity Class that are suposed to make my character spawn in the right place it doesn't work at all!

---

Game.player.setX(xx*16);
Game.player.setY(yy*16);

---

Here's my Entity Class for you to see if i did something wrong, and again, i did everything exactely like int the vídeo an in the vídeo it worked.

```
public class Entity {

    public static BufferedImage LIFEPACK_EN = Game.spritesheet.getSprite(78, 0, 16, 16);
    public static BufferedImage WEAPON_EN = Game.spritesheet.getSprite(96, 0, 16, 16);
    public static BufferedImage BULLET_EN = Game.spritesheet.getSprite(78, 16, 16, 16);
    public static BufferedImage ENEMY_EN = Game.spritesheet.getSprite(96, 16, 16, 16);
    
    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    
    private BufferedImage sprite;
    
    public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage sprite) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }
    
    public void setX(int newX) {
        this.x = newX;
    }
    
    public void setY(int newY) {
        this.x = newY;
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return (int)this.x;
    }
    
    public int getY() {
        return (int)this.y;
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }
    
    public void update() {
        
    }
    
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(sprite, this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. We don't know the context of how these classes are used. *is spawning in the up middle corner of the screen.* - sounds like the layout manager is controlling the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I saw where I was wrong.

```
public void setY(int newY) {
    this.x = newY;
```

In this line code here, it's suposed to be `this.y` and I thought that I did that, but I couldn't see.